# Dropping IE6 Support; What Do We Gain? ... HTML / CSS / JavaScript Functionality & Techniques

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-6, backwards-compatibility

The web development community is at the tipping point of ditching Internet Explorer 6 support - even Microsoft is counting down it's demise http://ie6countdown.com/!

This raises a very interesting question... ***What do we gain?***

We've been weighed down by the ball and chain that is IE6 for so long it's really interesting to consider *all the good stuff we've neglected*...

With IE7 as the new baseline for backwards compatibility, how will this impact web development? What HTML, CSS or JavaScript functionality / techniques can we now *expect* from our browsers?

For example, I'm really looking forward to being able to use **CSS Chained Classes**.

```
.class1.class2.class3 {
  background: #fff;
}

<div class="class1 class2 class3">
  <p>Content here.</p>
</div>
```

P.S This question was inspired by [CSS Differences in Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/) from [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/).

Comment: Close voters: how is this not a real question? It's pretty clear what's being asked and I think good answers would be quite valuable.

Comment: It's not a real question because it's so broad. It's not about any specific "programming problem". It's basically a request for a blog post, of which there are a billion out there on this very subject.

Comment: Don't close it, but I'd say it's probably community wiki.

Comment: @Pointy: I suppose. I do think that in the popular rush to drop IE 6 there has been something of a lack of objective appraisal of what is actually gained by doing so, which is less than one might think.

Comment: @Tim Down's current answer is the kind of response I'm looking for (plus answers regarding how removing IE6 from the picture affects our development process as a whole). I realise this question is a bit open ended (no clear answer) so if the Stack Overflow community feel this Question is better suited to a Community Wiki could someone with enough reputation please do this - I would hate to see this closed completely. Thank you.

Comment: I, for one, will be glad to finally ditch the incompatible box models...

Comment: From IE6 to IE7, the major gains are that IE7 supports a number of CSS selectors that were missing in IE6. IE7 also fixed many of the most painful IE6 bugs, which frees us from many of the painful hacks that were previously required. IE7 was also massively more secure than IE6 - when Google got hacked last year, they blamed it on an IE6 flaw, and they've been actively dropping support for IE6 ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a web developer standpoint, there is surprisingly little in the way of extra functionality. Many standard APIs present in other browsers are still missing. The gain comes more in the shape of a lot of small improvements in IE7 compared to IE6.

- Improved but imperfect PNG transparency support
- Native `XMLHttpRequest` (not useful: ActiveX is still required for `file:` URLs)
- Some CSS layout fixes
- Much better CSS support, as laid out in the article linked in the question

Some things that haven't improved between IE 6 and 7:

- The JScript engine is still very slow relative to modern browsers, the JSCript API is missing many methods introduced by Mozilla that were copied in other browsers and later standardized, and JScript retains many quirks and bugs
- Many CSS layout issues are still present
- Some new CSS bugs were introduced

Comment: I think it's also important to note what's still broken. The PNG support is weak (try altering the opacity of a transparent PNG), and the JavaScript interpreter is horribly slow. There are layout fixes, but the layout engine is still awful, with legacy bugs and new bugs.

Comment: @Pointy: Agreed. I'll qualify those points.

Answer (score 0):

There are a boatload of rendering bugs that got fixed in ie7. 7 was more about working on the massive security issues with IE rather then how far behind it was feature wise. But fixing rendering bugs means that you have to do less hacky css stuff to get things looking right.

I think this is an even better site to be watching http://theie9countdown.com/